# Derivative of $\log(\det(X+X^T)/2 )$ with respect to $X$

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

I learned that the derivative of $\log(\det X)$ with respect to $X$ is $X^{-1}$. However, the following

> Calculate $$\dfrac{d(\log(\det(X+X^T)/2 ))}{dX}$$

makes me confused. Could somebody help me? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: As said by my colleague, you must know some basics about MathJax : enclosing expression between dollar signs, using backslash in front of operators like log, det etc. Besides, I have replaced your "prime" notation by a "transpose" which is the usual notation in mathematics.

Comment: can you confirm that it is the $\log[\det(\tfrac{X+X^T}{2})]$ (I have voluntarily uses square brackets) because 2 parentheses are missing in the title in particular.

Comment: Yes, you mean it, and thank you. This is the first time I raised a question here.

Comment: The [matrix cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=3274) is your friend in situations like this. It doesn't have this exact case in there but it is good to understand the general principles therein.

Comment: Aha, thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Michael Grant , I'm crumbling down when I read that you recommend reading the matrix cookbook. Indeed, many students who do not understand one word about differentiation, rush to this book and recopy the formulas that are inside, without understanding their meaning. In a second step, since they cannot find anything, they come back to MSE in order to get a solution of their problem.

Comment: @loupblanc yes, that is an inevitable consequence of having such a nice resource.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use (called Jacobi formula) that
$$ \frac{\partial \det(X)}{\partial x_{i,j}} = adj(X)^T_{i,j}, \text{ or equivalently } \ \frac{d \det(X)}{d X} = adj(X)^T. $$
the above comes from the following identity
$$ A \cdot adj(A)^T = \det(A)\quad \forall\ A\in M(\mathbb{R},n).$$
So that you can compute
$$ \frac{d \log(\det(X+X^T)/2)}{d X} = \frac{adj(X+X^T)^T}{\det(X+X^T)} = (X+X^T)^{-1}. $$

Comment: This is off by a factor of 2. The answer should read $$2(X+X^T)^{-1}$$

Comment: Well no because the factor 2 is inside the logarithm but outside the determinant, so that $d( \log(f(x)/C) ) = d( \log(f(x)) - \log(C) ) = d(\log(f(x)))$.